# Display an inline element underneath an inline element

Tags: html, css

I have a series of inline lists. I would like to position some below the others. I cannot change markup. An example of this is below:

```css
.lists ul {
  display: inline-grid;
}

#under-first {
  /*I've tried:
  float: left;
  grid-row: 1;
  and changing the lists uls to flex and doing:
  order: 1
  */ 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="under-first">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The red colored list with the ID of "under-first" I want to somehow position underneath the first list. I've tried `grid-row` along with changing to flex and playing around with `order` but doing that just moves the list around and doesn't actually position it directly below where I want it to go.

How can I go best about doing this? I even tried doing a float.

Comment: I'd look into [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mixins). You can change [the order of child items pretty easily](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one, if you insist using **grid**:

```css
.lists {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

#under-first {
  color: red;
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="under-first">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should create a snippet so we can see it working!

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex, add max-width to have a wrapping then adjust order:

```css
.lists {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 400px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#under-first {
  color: red;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="under-first">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Another idea without max-width. Simply set `flex-basis:100%` to the element so it get pushed to next row:

```css
.lists {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#under-first {
  color: red;
  order: 2;
  flex-basis:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="under-first">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The grid solutions are nice, super elegant.

Here's a solution using a few simple `position` properties - basically absolutely position the `#under-first` to the `left` and `bottom` of the lists.

```css
.lists {
  position: relative;
}

.lists ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.lists ul li {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

#under-first {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="under-first">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```